# How many possible ways are there to reach at the goal?

Tags: combinatorics

Assuming that the distance between an intersection and the adjacent ones is equal for all intersections, how many possible ways are there to reach at the "goal" walking from the "start"?

You are allowed to take a roundabout way only once (you can move down or left, including backtracking, only once), but you are not allowed to move once you get the goal.

Every time I calculate, I get different answers.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: I advise you to validate the solution by @paw88789 : you will not find a better one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Case 1: No backtrack.  There are ten total steps, $5$ east, $5$ north. Total for this case:
${{10}\choose{5}}$ routes.

Case 2: One West step: So there will be $5$ north steps, $6$ east steps, and $1$ west step.  However we have to be sure not to go off the grid.  So the west step can't be before the first or after the last east step.

Choose $5$ slots for the north steps ${{12}\choose{5}}$ routes.

Fill the first and last remaining slot with east steps.  ($1$ way).

Choose one of the five remaining slots for the west step. ($5$ ways).

The remaining slots are east steps. (1 way).

Total for case 2: ${{12}\choose{5}}\cdot 5$

Case 3: Similar to case 2 but with a south step (and a corresponding extra north step).

Same total as case 2.

---

Edit as suggested by Harry K. (Thanks!) The problem statement says that you can't move once the goal has been reached.  Hence each of cases 2 and 3 should have their count reduced by $1$ (they can't end with east, west; or south, north respectively, as either of these would violate the rule of don't move after goal is reached).

Comment: Very good solution !

Comment: I think a way like "EEEEENNNNNWE" is included in your solution, which is against the rule. (you are not allowed to move once you get the goal)

Comment: @Harry K.  Good catch.  I will edit.

Answer (score 2):

Partial solution :

Let use the initial of the cardinal directions for coding our paths (for example ENENENENEN for a staircase pattern without backtrack or ENNWNEEENNEE if there is a "western move". You have explained that you are allowed to use letter W at most once or letter S at most once.

One can split the paths into 3 non overlapping categories :

**Category A:** paths coded with 10 letters "E" and "N" (no "W", no "S"): there are $$a:=\binom{10}{5}=252$$ of them (number of ways to select the 5 places where you desire to place a "N" among 10 places) ).

**Category B:** paths coded with 12 letters : one "W", 6 "E", 5 "N" ; there are **a priori** $b_1:=12!(6! 5!)=5544$ of them but **beware** we must subtract to this number the number $b_2$ of "nonsensical" paths

- either with an initial or a final "W" , i.e., suppress $$2 \times 11!/(6! 5!)=2 \times 462$$ cases,
- **but also other intermediate cases** like "NNW..." corresponding to paths going outside the $5 \times 5$ playground (**unless you allow them ?**).

**Category C:** paths coded with one "S", 6 "N", 5 'E": same count as before.

Therefore, the result is : $a+2(b_1-b_2)$

**But, it remains to find $b_2$...**

Comment: What will it be like when taking detour(moving down or left) is allowed?

Comment: I hadn't read well enough your question...

Comment: Let us name the moves in a different manner $E,N,W,S$; do you mean that we could have codes like this one : $EEENN(WE)NNENE$ , i.e. codes where one has "ways and backs" like my "WE" above, or are you allowed more complicated 'roudabouts" as you call them. I think you should make it clearer in your question...

Comment: I meant you’re allowed complicated roundabouts like “EEEWNENNNEN”

Comment: You need 12 letters in your last example : a supplementary E is needed. All right. Are you allowed to use letter W once only and/or letter S once only ? If this is the case, do we agree that there are 3 disjoint categories of paths : 1) coded with 10 letters (no W, no S), 2) with 12 letters (either an added W, or an added S), with 14 letters (an added W **and** an added S) ?

Comment: W cannot be used when S is used, vice versa. I mean: “twelve-letter paths” are allowed; “fourteen-letter paths” are not.

Comment: I am going to reconsider my answer.